# How do I make a UserControl that can bind to an ItemsSource or DataContext?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, mvvm

I'm trying to write a simple 2D map editor. Here's my code so far. How do I code the UserControl class that binds to a map? I can't seem to find an example of a UserControl that handles the ItemsSource like the built in ListBox and DataGrid do. I'm thinking I need to find out when ItemsSource gets set and then write code that subscribes to CollectionChanged and PropertyChanged and creates/deletes/positions Images? Should I even be trying to do this when I have 3 ObservableCollections to bind to?

```
public class Map
{
    public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<MapSquare>> Squares 
        = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<MapSquare>>();
}

public class MapSquare
{
    public ObservableCollection<MapTile> Items = new ObservableCollection<MapTile>();
}

public class MapTile : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private CroppedBitmap bmp;
    public CroppedBitmap Bitmap { 
        get{return bmp;}
        set{ bmp = value; OnPropertyChanged("Bitmap");}
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "like the built in ListBox and DataGrid", how similar do you mean? Do you just mean the broad ability to deal with a list-like source, or do you mean all the stuff that they can do - item generation, virtualization, item templating, container styling and so on?

The mechanism in `ItemsControl` that underpins all of the built in list binding in WPF is surprisingly complicated, so it would be a huge amount of effort to reproduce. Worse, there are lots of places where other bits of WPF know about `ItemsControl` and have special handling for it. (E.g., `ScrollViewer` and certain panels.) So it's not even possible to produce your own implementation that does exactly the same thing unless you also write your own replacements for all those other parts too.

`ItemsControl` is one of the most powerful features of WPF, but it's also one of the least well-factored. Basically, if you want its functionality, you pretty much have to use it.

So if you want your `UserControl` to include `ItemsControl` functionality, you'll need to put some sort of `ItemsControl` inside your `UserControl` and just wire your collection properties through to their `ItemsSource` properties. That may well be the best approach because you're getting the built-in `ItemsControl` implementation to do all the work for you.

But if you're only looking to reproduce some specific features, you could handle the collection change events. But I'd only go down that path if you've exhausted the option of getting `ItemsControl` to do it for you.

Comment: I thought I was just going to need to create/delete/update items - but after a quick implementation (not using MVVM) I'm discovering that I'll definitely need virtualization. Loading/changing a grid of 50x100 Images is very very slow. I'm going to put a big canvas inside a ScrollViewer and in the OnScroll event I'm going to create/remove Images so that only what would be onscreen is actually there.